# Using gdal_translate in command line with for loop to convert from .h5 to .tif

Tags: python, command-line, hdf5, tiff, gdal

I am trying to use a for loop within the command line to convert a group of .h5 files into .tif files within a directory.  I don't think I am too far off base but I am a little stumped.

Is someone able to please provide how I would write this for loop to get my .h5 files (plural) to convert and written (saved) as .tif files?

Thanks

`!FOR %i IN (*.h5) DO gdal_translate -of GTiff HDF5:"C:/MyPath/"%i://subdataset C:/mypath/%i -a_srs EPSG:XXXX -a_ullr -XX XX XX XX`

The goal is to have the for loop go through each .h5 file located in the directory and convert them to the same name but as a .tif file so example would be something like "100.h5" being converted as a separate file "100.tif" so that the .h5 file is not overwritten but saved in the same location (folder)

I keep bouncing around with errors from permission denied messages to destination file issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to resolve this on my own with the following command line code `!FOR %G IN (*.h5) DO (gdal_translate -of GTiff HDF5:"enter directory here"/%G://enter subdirectory here D:/Model_v6/translated/%G.tif -a_srs EPSG:XXXX -a_ullr XX XX XX XX)` for anyone who may have this issue in the future.  Cheers